# How to save&restore DNNClassifier trained in TensorFlow python; iris example

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to TensorFlow, just started learning a few days ago. I've completed this tutorial(https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/tflearn/index.html#tf-contrib-learn-quickstart) and applied the exact same idea to my own data set. (which came out pretty good!)

Now I'd like to save&restore the trained DNNClassifier for further use. If anyone know how to do that, please let me know by using the iris example code in the link above. Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

found the solution to this? In case you didn't  you can do this specifying the model_dir parameter on the constructor when creating the DNNClassifier, this will create all the checkpoints and files in this directory(the saving step). When you want to do the restore step, you just create another DNNClassifier passing the same model_dir parameter(restore phase) , this will restore the model from the files created the first time.

Hope this helps to you.

Comment: I'm sorry to be delayed to respond to your first comment... And thanks so much for the help!!! I will try that today! I only tried using model_dir in initialization, but called restore function to load up trained classifier. It complained about model.def missing, but your suggestion is not calling restore function and instead just initialize DNNClassifier with its constructor by setting the path to model_dir correct?

Comment: Yep, exactly , you use model_dir parameter on the constructor of DNNclassifier and this saves the model, for restoring you just create another DNNClassifier with the same model_dir and it will read the files generated

Comment: Did your solution actually work? I'm getting the following error: ValueError: Either linear_feature_columns or dnn_feature_columns should be defined.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure how I could fit my code here, so posted it as a new answer below. Please take a look! I'm using v9.0 TensorFlow with Python 2.7. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ohhh , i think i see your problem, theres a bug in tensorflow and  altough you have this model_dir parameter to restore your model , it cant be used right away, so you have to make at least some "dummy" training after restoring it,  that means you have to run "fit" again at least one step:


classifier.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, steps=2);

This will take your saved model ,and perform a "dummy" training so it can be used again.

Comment: Awesome! It worked just as I wanted! Many thanks... But how did you figure this out? I mean what made you to think that this "dummy" training would work? I'd love to know just for my learning sake. I see now the model.def file newly created in the specified path now...

Comment: Im glad it worked for you!! to be honest , like many things in machine learning, i figured it out by testing/error . Cant remember what exactly led me to find this. Happy coding!

Comment: And how can I exactly perform a dummy training? Where should I get x_train and y_train if not from the csv? It seems to me like training a new model and saving it. Shouldn't it go without loading a csv file in the script if I use a new one?

Comment: Hi, with dummy we were refering to the action of training for at least one step after loading your saved model. The flow will be something like:
- Train your model(using model_dir), this will save the checkpoints and model definition.
- When you need to restore your saved model, you instantiate your object using same model_dir.
- Perform a train for one step, you can use an training example of your original train set,this will load the definition.

I know is not the cleanest way, but its the only way while tensorflow developers give us the official save/restore process.

Answer (score 1):

Below is my Code...

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
# Data sets
IRIS_TRAINING = "iris_training.csv"
IRIS_TEST = "iris_test.csv"

# Load datasets.
training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv(filename=IRIS_TRAINING, target_dtype=np.int)
test_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv(filename=IRIS_TEST, target_dtype=np.int)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = training_set.data, test_set.data, training_set.target, test_set.target

# Build 3 layer DNN with 10, 20, 10 units respectively.
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[10, 20, 10], n_classes=3, model_dir="path_to_my_local_dir")

# print classifier.model_dir

# Fit model.
print "start fitting model..."
classifier.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, steps=200)
print "finished fitting model!!!"

# Evaluate accuracy.
accuracy_score = classifier.evaluate(x=x_test, y=y_test)["accuracy"]
print('Accuracy: {0:f}'.format(accuracy_score))

#Classify two new flower samples.
new_samples = np.array(
    [[6.4, 3.2, 4.5, 1.5], [5.8, 3.1, 5.0, 1.7]], dtype=float)
y = classifier.predict_proba(new_samples)
print ('Predictions: {}'.format(str(y)))

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#model_dir below has to be the same as the previously specified path!
new_classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[10, 20, 10], n_classes=3, model_dir="path_to_my_local_dir")
accuracy_score = new_classifier.evaluate(x=x_test, y=y_test)["accuracy"]
print('Accuracy: {0:f}'.format(accuracy_score))
new_samples = np.array(
    [[6.4, 3.2, 4.5, 1.5], [5.8, 3.1, 5.0, 1.7]], dtype=float)
y = classifier.predict_proba(new_samples)
print ('Predictions: {}'.format(str(y)))
```

Comment: Is this code actually an answer to your own question? If it is just showing what is your problem, then please include it in the question.