# Tensorflow: How can I restore model for training? (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, tensorflow

I want to train a cnn for 20000 steps. In the 100th step I want to save all variables and after that I want to re-run my code restoring model and starting from the 100th step. I am trying to make it work with tensorflow documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/variables/index.html but I can't. Any help?

Comment: Have you tried following the steps in this documentation on [saving and restoring a TensorFlow model](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/tensorflow/5000/saving-and-restoring-a-model-in-tensorflow#t=201608112143154413759)?

Comment: That's not what I want. I want to "pause" my training every 100 steps etc. saving and restoring for the next run of my code.

Comment: I am not sure how that differs from saving and restoring as @mrry pointed out - except that you may have control flow vars. These you can save easily with built-in python/numpy functionality, like numpy.save, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Im stuck in something similar but maybe this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3340) can help you. Im new in tensorflow but i think you cant restore and fit without need to training again you model.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that you can do this using DNNClassifier. The problem here is that I have a for loop and I want every 100 steps stop running my code. After that I want to restore the model and continue from the previous step. The classifier that I am using is AdamOptimizer and it does not provide model_dir paramater.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for checkpoints ? I think i read something about that before but have not try it by my self. I did a fast reading and [this](https://nathanbrixius.wordpress.com/2016/05/24/checkpointing-and-reusing-tensorflow-models/) could give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is still unstable , and the documentation is outdated so is confusing, what worked for me(this was a suggestion of  people from google that works directly on tensorflow) was to use the model_dir parameter on the constructor of my models before training, in this you will tell where to store your model, after training you just instantiate again  a model using the same model_dir and it will restore the model from the files and checkpoints generated.

Comment: Please see my answers and see if they are useful for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38358419/how-to-saverestore-dnnclassifier-trained-in-tensorflow-python-iris-example/38489883#38489883

Comment: As I previously answered I am using for loop without DNNClassifier. My Classifier is AdamOptimizer and it does not provide model_dir argument. Maybe I should try with MetaGraph?

Comment: My problem is mentioned here more precisely: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3765 Take a look. Thanks!