# Save and restore Experimenter/Estimator in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm writing a program that trains 4 neural networks and collects their outcomes to find a better result. I will use an ensemble method to do it, but the question is not about it.

The problem is about restoring each model after the training process. 
I found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38358419/how-to-saverestore-dnnclassifier-trained-in-tensorflow-python-iris-example) about it, but it doesn't help at all.

## (Pseudo)-code

My English is not really good, so I will try to explain my workflow using a pseudo-python-code:

```
for i in range(4):
    # Create the estimator (a DNNClassifier).
    estimator = build_estimator(...)
    # Train the model.
    estimator.fit(input_fn=...)

# Do other stuffs...

for i in range(4):
    # Restore the estimator using the same arguments.
    estimator = build_estimator(...)
    # Predict the input data.
    predictions[i] = estimator.predict(input_fn=...)

    # Do others stuffs using the predictions collection.
```

## Error

This is, in broad terms, my code and, even if it looks good and straightforward, it doesn't work. This error is shown during the restore part and it means that my DNN wasn't saved properly.

```
2017-07-24 11:40:24.517773: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key dnn/hiddenlayer_1/weights not found in checkpoint
2017-07-24 11:40:24.517884: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key dnn/hiddenlayer_0/biases not found in checkpoint
2017-07-24 11:40:24.518739: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key dnn/hiddenlayer_0/weights not found in checkpoint
2017-07-24 11:40:24.519621: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key dnn/logits/biases not found in checkpoint
2017-07-24 11:40:24.519684: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key dnn/hiddenlayer_1/biases not found in checkpoint
2017-07-24 11:40:24.519861: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key dnn/hiddenlayer_2/weights not found in checkpoint
2017-07-24 11:40:24.519947: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key dnn/hiddenlayer_2/biases not found in checkpoint
2017-07-24 11:40:24.522592: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key dnn/logits/weights not found in checkpoint
```

## Note

1. The DNNClassifier has been created and restored using the same arguments.
2. As far as I know I don't need to save any checkpoints because the DNNClassifier does it during the training process.
3. I read somewhere that before to use `predict` an `evaluation` is required. I tried, but nothing was changed.
4. I can share other fragment of my code if you want, but I don't think that can help you more.

Answer (score -1):

you should create model like this:

estimator = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier( feature_columns=feature_cols, hidden_units=[10,10,10], n_classes=2 , model_dir= your_path)

estimator.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn1(training data), steps=1000)

estimator_predict = estimator.predict(input_fn=lambda: input_fn1(test_data))

Comment: You miss the point: I know how to create an estimator and predict data runtime. but I cannot restore properly. Between your `fit` and `predict` I could also halt the program.

Comment: can you check in the path where your model is stored. that index, checkpoint files will be created there.